# how can i monitoring the same service on different host with only one alarm?

Tags: service, monitoring, nagios

i am new in nagios and i want to group of "services states" in different host in only one alarm.
For example, i have three hosts with the service httpd (ONLY ONE SERVICE) and i want to generate one alarm considering the different case:

1. IF  host1(ok) and host2 (ok) and host3(ok) --> generate ONLY ONE alarm in nagios to notify that the service httpd is ok.
2. IF host1(ok) and host2 (critical) and host3(ok) --> generate ONLY ONE alarm in nagios to notify that the service httpd is warning with one host critical.
3. IF host1(critical) and host2 (critical) and host3(critical) --> generate ONLY ONE alarm in nagios to notify that the service httpd is critical.

i was reading different forum, but in the most of case... they are using nagios to monitorize the service for each host, not to group service in one check.

aditional note: hots1, host2 and host3 belongs to the same hostgroup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible out-of-the box with Nagios. Other systems which are built ontop of Nagios add this functionality in different ways.  For example, [Opsview](http://www.opsview.com/) has what they call Business Service Monitoring which allows you to alert on groups of services.

If you're sticking with plain Nagios I think you'll need to write custom plugin as a wrapper for the `check_http` plugin.  It should be fairly straightforward to write a bash script to do this - it will just need to run `check_http` multiple times and aggregate the results in the way you want.